# $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-z} $ converges uniformly

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, riemann-zeta

Show that for every $ \delta > 0 $ the series

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-z} $$

converges uniformly on {  $ z $  | $ Re(z) > 1 + \delta $ }

Conclude that the series defines in {  $ z $  | $ Re(z) > 1 $ } the holomorphic function $\zeta(z) $

How to approach such thing? Bit confused :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|\frac 1 {n^{z}}|=\frac 1 {n^{x}}$ where $x =\Re z$. Since$\sum \frac  1 {n^a}<\infty$ for $a =1+\delta$ we can apply M-test.

Uniform convergence implies that the sum is anlaytic because it is the uniform limit of the partial sums which are analytic functions.